# subsonic - Offset and length were out of bounds for the array intermittent error

Tags: subsonic, offset, indexoutofboundsexception

inherited a website which uses subsonic 2.0 and gets an intermittent error of "Offset and length were out of bounds for the array" . If we were to restart the app or recycle the app pool, the issue would go away. I suspect it has something to do with subsonic caching the table schema based on the error log below. Has anyone experience this issue and can suggest a fix?

```
System.ArgumentException
```

Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.
   at System.Array.BinarySearch[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2.IndexOfKey(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2.ContainsKey(TKey key)
   at SubSonic.DataService.GetSchema(String tableName, String providerName, TableType tableType)
   at SubSonic.DataService.GetTableSchema(String tableName, String providerName)
   at SubSonic.Query..ctor(String tableName)
   at G05.ProductController.GetProductByColorName(Int32 productId, String colorName) in C:\Projects\G05\Code\BusinessLogic\ProductController.vb:line 514

Answer (score 0):

Strange that it's intermittent . How are the objects being generated? Is it using the .abp file? If so, I'd recommend running the files through the subcommander to hard generate the classes. That way the generation of the objects isn't ever executed on production environment.